# Make removable notification with FLAG_NO_CLEAR

Tags: java, android

Hello i have a Notification with this flags:

```
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
```

if I want to make it remove them from another class how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Your notification will have a unique Id so that you could clear it out from another class programmatically in this way:

```
public static void clearOutNotification(Context context, int notificationID) {
    // Clear our notification
    if (Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE != null) {
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(ns);
        nMgr.cancel(notificationID);
    }
}
```